# Finding the command for a specific PID in Linux from Python

Tags: python, linux, process

I'd like to know if it's possible to find out the "command" that a PID is set to. When I say command, I mean what you see in the last column when you run the command "top" in a linux shell. I'd like to get this information from Python somehow when I have a specific PID.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a /proc files has a disadvantage of lower portability, which may or may not be a concern. Here's how you can use the standard shell command for that

```
ps -w -w -p <YOUR PID> -o cmd h
```

Note the two `-w` options that instructs ps to not truncate the output (which it does by default)

Reading its output from python is as simple as calling a single function `subprocess.check_output()` documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: All sort of true, but the question was for linux, so we did answer the actual question, and I think most of us made the assumption that he knew about `ps(1)`.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: then the question would sound like "Where does `ps` take command line info from?"

Comment: ps works by reading the virtual files in /proc. So much for the well-defined POSIX interface (which one was that, anyway?).

Comment: Listen, I would have marked you both as correct answers but I couldn't. Pavel's answer just seemed to be more of what I was looking for but the answer given for DigitalRoss was great too. Upvotes for both.

Comment: @Nick Stinemates, @Michael Foukarakis.  Hey, I know how ps works (yes, it indeed reads files in `/proc`).  But when instead of `/proc` they'll invent `/foobar` system, you'll have to rewrite your program.  Anyway, maybe I've been braindamaged by working in LSB workgroup, but you really should stick to standards where it's enough for you--which is the case under consideration.

Comment: This command will output the command line args, but separate them with spaces. If you're trying to split the arguments back into a list of strings, you won't be able to differentiate between args, and args with spaces. (Which you *can* do with `/proc/$PID/cmdline`)

Comment: This command will truncate the command line if it's too long. And I second what @Thanatos said: it doesn't work for arguments containing spaces. This is the equivalent of [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for processes.

Comment: Haha wow look at the way I used to communicate thirteen (wow) years ago.  I've edited the post and fixed the truncation issue

Answer (score 8):

An interesting Python package is [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#readme).

For example, to get the command for a specific PID:

```
import psutil
pid = 1234 # The pid whose info you're looking for
p = psutil.Process(pid)
print(p.cmdline())
```

The last line will print something like `['/usr/bin/python', 'main.py']`.

A more robust way to get this information, being careful if the pid represents a process no longer running:

```
import psutil
pid = 1234 # The pid whose info you're looking for
if pid in psutil.get_pid_list():
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    print(p.cmdline())
```

Answer (score 7):

Look in `/proc/$PID/cmdline`, and then os.readlink() on `/proc/$PID/exe`.

`/proc/$PID/cmdline` is not necessarily going to be correct, as a program can change its argument vector or it may not contain a full path. Three examples of this from my current process list are:

- `avahi-daemon: chroot helper`
- `qmgr -l -t fifo -u`
- `/usr/sbin/postgrey --pidfile=/var/run/postgrey.pid --daemonize --inet=127.0.0.1:60000 --delay=55`

That first one is obvious - it's not a valid path or program name. The second is just an executable with no path name. The third looks ok, but that whole command line is actually in `argv[0]`, with spaces separating the arguments. Normally you should have NUL separated arguments.

All this goes to show that `/proc/$PID/cmdline` (or the ps(1) output) is not reliable.

However, nor is `/proc/$PID/exe`. Usually it is a symlink to the executable that is the main text segment of the process. But sometimes it has " `(deleted)`" after it if the executable is no longer in the filesystem.

Also, the program that is the text segment is not always what you want. For instance, `/proc/$PID/exe` from that `/usr/sbin/postgrey` example above is `/usr/bin/perl`. This will be the case for all interpretted scripts (#!).

I settled on parsing `/proc/$PID/cmdline` - taking the first element of the vector, and then looking for spaces in that, and taking all before the first space. If that was an executable file - I stopped there. Otherwise I did a readlink(2) on `/proc/$PID/exe` and removed any " `(deleted)`" strings on the end. That first part will fail if the executable filename actually has spaces in it. There's not much you can do about that.

BTW. The argument to use ps(1) instead of `/proc/$PID/cmdline` does not apply in this case, since you are going to fall back to `/proc/$PID/exe`. You will be dependent on the `/proc` filesystem, so you may as well read it with read(2) instead of pipe(2), fork(2), execve(2), readdir(3)..., write(2), read(2). While ps and `/proc/$PID/cmdline` may be the same from the point of view of lines of python code, there's a whole lot more going on behind the scenes with ps.

Comment: Great write-up. Thanks for this, camh.

Answer (score 5):

Read up on the [`ps`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) command and parse its output.

```
ps -p [PID] -o cmd
```

should do it

Comment: This command will truncate the command line if it's too long, and doesn't work for arguments containing spaces (see [Thanatos's comment here](/q/1440941/#comment17143459_1441057) for details).

Answer (score 5):

#### Look in `/proc/$PID/cmdline`

Answer (score 0):

The proc filesystem exports this (and other) information.
Look at the /proc/PID/cmd symlink.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def filter_non_printable(str):
    ret=""
    for c in str:
        if ord(c) > 31 or ord(c) == 9:
            ret += c
        else:
            ret += " "
    return ret


#
# Get /proc/<cpu>/cmdline information
#
def pid_name(pid):
    try:
        with open(os.path.join('/proc/', pid, 'cmdline'), 'r') as pidfile:
            return filter_non_printable(pidfile.readline())

    except Exception:
        pass
        return
```