# How to parse /proc/pid/cmdline

Tags: linux

I'm trying to split the cmdline of a process on Linux but it seems I cannot rely on it to be separated by '\0' characters. Do you know why sometimes the '\0' character is used as separator and sometimes it is a regular space?

Do you know any other ways of retrieving the executable name and the path to it? I have been trying to get this information with 'ps' but it always returns the full command line and the executable name is truncated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

use `strings`

```
$ cat /proc/self/cmdline | strings -1
cat
/proc/self/cmdline
```

Comment: For `busybox` users: `cat /proc/self/cmdline | strings -n 1`

Comment: This is my preferred way too, but while _most_ distros come with `strings` by default, almost _no_ Docker base-images do. So, **YMMV**.

Answer (score 20):

The `/proc/PID/cmdline` is *always* separated by NUL characters.

To understand spaces, execute this command:

```
cat -v /proc/self/cmdline "a b" "c d e"
```

EDIT: If you really see spaces where there shouldn't be any, perhaps your executable (intentionally or inadvertently) writes to `argv[]`, or is using `setproctitle()`?

When the process is started by the kernel, cmdline is NUL-separated, and the [kernel code simply copies](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/fs/proc/base.c#L253) the range of memory where `argv[]` was at process startup into the output buffer when you read `/proc/PID/cmdline`.

Comment: As I said above, while I was explaining the "solution" to a coworker, I realized his cmdlines wasn't behave like I was expecting. We both are using Ubuntu, so I don't know if this is a behavior that can be configured or depends on the Kernel used.

Comment: This is wrong. Sometimes there are spaces separating the arguments - i.e. it's all in argv[0]. I know this because I have see this.

Comment: The mutability of the argument vector by the program is why I objected to your statement. If you hadn't said "always" and emphasised it, I wouldn't have commented.

Comment: Uhm, interesting. I have to check but I believed it happened for all of the processes. I don't remember which was the process I checked. Thanks for the update :)

Comment: I always believed they'd be NUL separated until I found a process where it wasn't. That was postgrey - a perl program using Net::Server which rewrites the command line, all in one argument.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think it's correct to say that there are ever spaces separating the *arguments* (as in members of argv[]), however, there may be spaces *within* an argument, possibly separating subparts which someone (mistakenly?) *intended* to be treated as distinct arguments.

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
tr "\0" " " /proc/2634/cmdline
```

to get the args separated by blanks, as you would see it on a command line.

Beware though that printing it this way there is not way to distinguish an argument with space in it ("a b") from two separate arguments ("a" "b").

Comment: No need to use "cat+tr" when "tr" alone can do it, see @hek2mgl answer.

Comment: Pipe to `tr "\0" "\n"` if you want each argument on a separate line, which is sometimes useful for readability w/ complex command lines.

Answer (score 17):

The command line arguments in `/proc/PID/cmdline` are terminated by null bytes. You can use `tr` to replace them by new lines:

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/"$PID"/cmdline
```

Comment: vendor boxes don't always have 'strings', they often have 'tr'.

Answer (score 4):

A shot in the dark, but is it possible that `\0` is separating terms and spaces are separating words within a term? For example,

```
myprog "foo bar" baz
```

might appear in `/proc/pid/cmdline` as...

```
/usr/bin/myprog\0foo bar\0baz
```

Complete guess here, I can't seem to find any spaces on one of my Linux boxes.

Comment: Hi. As you mention, spaces are used to separate words in the same term, this was what I was expecting, but I have access to a machine which is using spaces to separate terms too. It was an Ubuntu, don't know which release.

Answer (score 3):

Super-simple (but for only one process, not bulk parsing, etc):

```
$ cat /proc/self/cmdline "a b" "cd e" | xargs -0
```

How it works: by default, `xargs` just `echo`'es its input, and switch `-0` allows it to read null-separated lines rather than newline-separated ones.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440941/finding-the-command-for-a-specific-pid-in-linux-from-python/1443544#1443544). It covers what I found when trying to do this myself.

Edit: Have a look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/linux.debian.user/browse_thread/thread/36bdeb2406c456f9) thread on debian-user for a bash script that tries its best to do what you want (look for version 3 of the script in that thread).

Comment: Hi. 

I'm already doing something similar to track processes by its path, reading the exe symlink, but the big issue is to get the executable name in the cmd. I mean, usually, when you refer to a process executable you say: "I want the PID of emacs" so you expect to find "emacs", not "/usr/bin/emacs22-gtk" as the exe points to. 

What I haven't taken into account is the '(Deleted)' string reported by readlink. If I could properly split the information in cmdline I could mix its information with the one provided by the 'exe'.

In any case, it seems there is not an evident way :). Thanks!

Comment: I added a link to a thread where I posted a script that contains my implementation. It wont handle an executable name with a space in it, but they're rare (so rare that I've never seen one)

Answer (score 1):

Executable name:

```
cat /proc/${pid}/comm
```

Executable path:

```
readlink -f /proc/${pid}/exe
```

If you have a recent bash, you can use mapfile to split the command line into its arguments and put them in an array "command_line" like this:

```
mapfile -d '' -t command_line < "/proc/${pid}/cmdline"
```

Much more about /proc/ here:
[proc(5) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)