# Bash: get canonical path and args from pid

Tags: linux, bash, process, pid

Is there an easy way to get the canonical path and arguments that a certain process (pid) was run with.

For example, for process 1445 I would like to get:
`/usr/bin/xclock -digital`

What I was thinking of doing is:

```
$ ls -l /proc/1445 | grep exe
```

to get something like
`....... -> /usr/bin/xclock`

and then

```
$ ps 1445 | cut -b 28- | tail -n 1
```

to get `xclock -digital`

And finish by putting these two outputs together. I think this could work but I think there should be a better way to do this.

And help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the content of `/proc/$PID/cmdline` to get the path and the arguments (see [How to parse /proc/pid/cmdline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585989/how-to-parse-proc-pid-cmdline) for more details).

The canonical path can be obtained with `realpath(1)`.

Comment: Will it work if PATH at the time of executing e.g. xclock was set to use a different xclock from e.g. /home/user/bin/xclock? (with another xclock in /usr/bin in the "normal" PATH). Or would further analysis of the environment from the ps output need to be done for that?

Comment: Yes it should work but you won't know which xclock is running if you simply call `xclock`. To know which program is running, you can look at `/proc/$PID/exe`.