# Is it possible to get to know which script a python process is running?

Tags: python, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the command for a specific PID in Linux from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440941/finding-the-command-for-a-specific-pid-in-linux-from-python)

I currently have a python process (and its pid, of course) and I wondered if it is possible to find out which script this process is running. (I use Ubuntu Linux 10.04.4 LTS)

Comment: It's not listed in the command line arguments to that process?

Comment: @Thanatos What are command line arguments to a process? How to I get to know them? Do you mean the arguements that appear if I enter `man myProgram` or `myProgram --help`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cat /proc/${pid}/cmdline | tr '\0' ' '
```

The `cmdline` pseudo-file contains a process's command line arguments as a NUL-separated list of strings. The `tr` command translates the NULs to spaces.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Even with command line arguments :-) But why are the spaces skipped?

Comment: @moose: because `cmdline` contains NUL-separated command line components. Edited the answer.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1 and accept in a few minutes)! Do you know a website where I can read more about the process folder and the meaning of the files that are in `/proc/${pid}/`?

Comment: You could start by reading `man 5 proc` and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux).

Comment: @larsmans Why do you duplicate already existing answers?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: because I don't always bother to go looking for duplicates, though I will vote when someone else points them out.